# Vakil Exercise 3.2.H

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Is the following correct?

The maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ corresponding to $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$ and $(-\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$ (which are two Galois-conjugate points of $\mathbb{A}^2_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$) should be $(x^2-2, x-y)$. Whereas, that corresponding to the pair $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$ and $(\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$, should be $(x^2-2, x+y)$.

Comment: Well, can you prove it?